# Exception #0 : Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in ../Calendar.php PHP 7.4

Tags: magento2.4.2

I did a new installation of Magento 2.4.2 (PHP 7.4.3). There were no errors during the installation.
The ShopURL is running.
The backend login also works.
After I switched the backend to German, the following error message occurs:

```
"Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /myPath2project/shop/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Calendar.php on line 114"
```

Where could I start to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance
Greetings heiko

Answer (score 1):

I switched PHP to PHP 7.3.8 as a test. Now everything is working perfect.
Then these specifications are only partially correct.

[Magento System requirements](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html)